# Google Closure in C++/Qt QML Project

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, google-closure

Our team works on a C++ project using Qt/QML for the GUI part of our software. Apart from that we are a big fan of the boost libraries.
I'm now looking into possibilities to have a boost-like multi purpose javascript library in our project since we have a lot of reoccurring tasks to do (e.g. math, math-clamp, file handling). Google Closure seems to cover most of this stuff, but I'm unsure if it's possible to integrate it in our project.

Does anyone have suggestion how to tackle this task? Is ist possible to use the Closure functions in QML?

Comment: As long as Closure is standard JavaScript, it will work. It might not perform as well under the QML's engine, but it should work correctly at the very least.

Comment: This seems like a "why don't you just try it?" kind of question.

Comment: Yes, Closure is standard JavaScript. Depending on the environment you might find it useful to override goog.provide, goog.require like is done for Node.js in the "bootstrap/nodejs.js".

Comment: Without knowing much of your application I would like to add that it is often a good idea to keep the QML side as declarative as possible, limiting the amount of application logic written in JavaScript so that there is a clear separation of concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll keep your advice in mind. By this time I also see it as a 'just try it' kind of question. Originally I was aiming more at how to integrate it in practice, but realised it's very depending on the individual project structure.